# hadoop eclipse plugin installation directory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins

I am new to hadoop and eclipse. Can anyone tell me the format of the Installation directory for hadoop eclipse plugin when try to add a new hadoop server. I googled and tried hours with no luck getting desperate... Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

1. your system should be installed with hadoop, make sure it is running.
2. you need to copy the "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-.jar" you may download it from google. into the "/eclipse/plugins" directory. After this you need to restart the eclipse.
3. In eclipse you need to configure hadoop configurations by giving respective port numbers and hostname

[for more refer this link....](https://youtu.be/Zn2t-F3grh0)

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*.jar" from your "/hadoop-*/contrib/eclipse-plugin directory" into the "/eclipse/plugins" directory. After this you need to restart the eclipse. But this doesn't work a few times. A possible reason could be the absence of a few jar files in the hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*.jar. Try this an d let me know it work for you - Extract the hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*.jar, and add the following 5 files into "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.203.0\lib - `commons-configuration-1.6.jar, commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar, commons-lang-2.4.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar.`
After this add the names of these jars into the "haoop-eclipse-plugin-*\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF" file. Your MANIFEST.MF file should look something like this -

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: 1.6.0_21-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MapReduce Tools for Eclipse
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.hadoop.eclipse;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.18
Bundle-Activator: org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.Activator
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.core.runtime,org.eclipse.jd
 t.launching,org.eclipse.debug.core,org.eclipse.jdt,org.eclipse.jdt.co
 re,org.eclipse.core.resources,org.eclipse.ui.ide,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,o
 rg.eclipse.debug.ui,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,org.eclipse.core.express
 ions,org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets,org.eclipse.ui.console,org.eclipse.ui
 .navigator,org.eclipse.core.filesystem,org.apache.commons.logging
Eclipse-LazyStart: true
Bundle-ClassPath: classes/,lib/hadoop-core.jar,lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar,lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar,lib/jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar,lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar,lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar,lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar
Bundle-Vendor: Apache Hadoop
```

After doing this re'jar' the package and replace the old "hadoop-eclipse-plugin-*.jar" in the /eclipse/plugins directory and restart the eclipse.